# How to extend sys.path using files?

Tags: python, site-packages

I'm using a python environment (iOS Pythonista) that does not have setuptools so setup.py within a python packages will not run. There is a site-packages dir that is added to sys.path. I'm looking for a clever way to gunzip packages from pypi into site-packages without having to move the actual package with the __init__.py into site-packages. I'd like to keep the folder with all the documentation in site-packages. Is there a way to use __init__.py or another python reserved file to extend the sys.path?

A simplified pypi package structure:

```
MyPackage-1.10.0/
    mypackage/
        __init__.py
        somethinga.py
    setup.py
```

Current way: Move mypackage into site-packages, discard the rest.

Or is there a way to use something like site-packages/__init__.py to add sys.path's for the package folders when site-packages is added to sys.path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create one ore more `.pth` files in `site-packages`; their contents will be added to `sys.path` when present.

From the [`site` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html):

> A path configuration file is a file whose name has the form `name.pth` and exists in one of the four directories mentioned above; its contents are additional items (one per line) to be added to `sys.path`. Non-existing items are never added to `sys.path`, and no check is made that the item refers to a directory rather than a file. No item is added to `sys.path` more than once. Blank lines and lines beginning with `#` are skipped. Lines starting with `import` (followed by space or tab) are executed.

Use it to add the full or relative paths to package directories to `sys.path`.

For example, for your `MyPackage-1.10.0` package, all you need is a `MyPackage-1.10.0.pth` file with the contents `MyPackage-1.10.0` on a line by itself for Python to add the full directory path to `sys.path`.